# Maytag Bravos Quiet Series dryer belt size

Tags: dryer

I need to replace the belt on my Maytag Bravos Quiet Series 300.

In my search it seems that the replacement belt is 92 1/4 inch length and 1/4 inch width.

This belt (I bought two that size from Lowes's) seem to be too short to fit over the tension and motor pullies.

I had previously purchased a kit to replace the rollers and belt.   I've looked back at that order and it lists the belt in the kit as 93.6L.  I am unable to find any similar belts for purchase.

Has anyone else had experience with changing belts on this model?

Comment: Have you checked and released the adjustment mechanism?

Comment: @SolarMike There is a tension arm with a spring.   But even stretched to its limit, the belt still doesn't fit.   If I actually detached the tension arm, there's no way I could reattach it once I had the belt in place.

Comment: There are loads of replacement parts suppliers available online. Have you checked with any of them to see if they have what you need? Generally, you look up your aplicance by exact make/model#, some even have different versions, and they can tell you the exact part for your exact need. Also, I'm not sure what "93.6L" is - sounds like it's a measurement in liters, which is volume, not length...

Comment: @FreeMan The "L" is referring to length.

Comment: Ah. Well, 92.25" L is shorter than 93.6" L, so it's not surprising that you can't get your new replacement to fit - it's ~1.25" too short. You may have to reorder the whole kit to get the right sized belt. If you do, may as well replace the rollers since you've got new ones. Keep the old ones as backups, just in case.

Comment: @FreeMan I have ended up doing this.   It should arrive tomorrow.  I'd rather just buy a single $8-10 belt rather the $20+ kit, but oh well.

Comment: I hear ya! Sadly, sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: As additional information, that kit did work then, but now (18ish months later) I'm faced with the same issue and this time the belt in the kit also seems too short...

Answer (score 2):

Since the belt doesn't appear to be available separately at the right length, your best bet is probably to buy the kit that contains the correct length belt and the replacement  rollers.

Since you'll have new rollers, you may was well put the new ones on. You can keep the old, low mileage rollers as spares, just in case something goes wrong with one of these new ones.